# HttpWebRequest to HTTPS site with redirect

Tags: c#, https, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to automate the reading of some information from an HTTPS page using HttpWebRequest.  The link I'm requesting normally redirects to a page that has login/password fields which are POSTed to a php file.

The code I have isn't working in that I'm just getting back the page information containing the form with username/password fields.

I'm not sure how I should handle this scenario.

Any assistance as always hugely appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
 NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://myaccount.talktalk.co.uk/myservices/bbusage/viewbbusage"); 
 request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
 request.Credentials = nc;
 request.Method = "POST";
 CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
 request.CookieContainer = cc;
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
 {    
     Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
```

This line is causing the redirect page to be skipped, as the HttpRequest automatically follows the redirect link before returning. If you wish to examine the redirect page then change this flag to false.

EDIT:

I may have misread the question, if you meant that you are attempting to get to the actual page (not the redirect or login pages) then you shouldn't be using NetworkCredential. NetworkCredential only works for Basic, Kerbos, and similar browser based authentication systems, the PHP site uses form based authentication, which requires you to perform the post request.

The solution in this case is to Get the login form, fill in the appropriate fields and post it, being sure to keep the cookies in tact, as your cookie container should at that point contain your authentication information.

Comment: Thanks for the response... Sorry to be dim, but could you post a little pseudo code to give an idea of the steps required?  Am I going to make multiple requests in that case?  Thanks once again.

Comment: @Darren: I would use [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to get a look at what the normal login page looks like, and follow [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) about how to POST. Finally make sure you attach your CookieCollection and maintain the object between calls.